# ios provision profile error

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, marmalade

I'm trying to build development version of application with provision profile included (for Push Notifications) and getting fail to install it. I've cleared all certificates and rebuild them all EXACTLY step-by-step as says http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/native/platformguides/iosguide/iossigning/iossigningassetssetup.html . When I include iphone-provisioning-profile in mkb file I have success build but if I try to install it on the iPhone 5/iPad 3 installation error occurs. If I build application without provisionprofile file - installation process ok. All devices has actual .provisionprofile files uploaded, iOS 6.1.2.

```
Marmalade Makefile Builder v6.2.1 [336699]
Copyright (C) 2001-2012 Marmalade.
e:\Marmalade\6.2\s3e\makefile_builder\mkb.py --verbose=1 e:/Marmalade/6.2/examples/s3e/s3eIOSNotifications/s3eIOSNotifications.mkb --deploy-only
Building project: e:/Marmalade/6.2/examples/s3e/s3eIOSNotifications/s3eIOSNotifications.mkb
setting root dir: e:\marmalade\6.2\examples\s3e
loading mkf: [e:\marmalade\6.2\examples\s3e] 'ExamplesMain'
loading mkf: [e:\marmalade\6.2\extensions] 's3eIOSNotifications'
loading mkf: [e:\marmalade\6.2\modules] 'iwutil'
package is deprecated
adding package reference: C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\APPLIC~1\Marmalade\packages\6.2.1\libjpeg_6b
loading mkf: [C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\APPLIC~1\Marmalade\packages\6.2.1\libjpeg_6b] 'libjpeg'
adding package reference: C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\APPLIC~1\Marmalade\packages\6.2.1\libpng_1.2.34
loading mkf: [C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\APPLIC~1\Marmalade\packages\6.2.1\libpng_1.2.34] 'libpng'
package is deprecated
adding package reference: C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\APPLIC~1\Marmalade\packages\6.2.1\zlib_1.2.4
loading mkf: [C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\APPLIC~1\Marmalade\packages\6.2.1\zlib_1.2.4] 'zlib'
using build directory 'build_s3eiosnotifications_vc9'
adding PATH: e:\marmalade\6.2\s3e\gcc\bin
using gcc toolchain: arm-none-eabi-gcc []
using RVCT version: 5.2
adding PATH: E:\DS-5\bin
using RVCT from: E:\DS-5\bin
found app.icf in data dir
adding PATH: e:\marmalade\6.2\s3e\bin
Wrote file 'deploy_config.py'.
adding PATH: e:\marmalade\6.2\tools\gcc\mips\android_mips_windows\bin
using gcc_mips toolchain: mipsel-linux-android-gcc []
Wrote file 'linker_script'.
done
Doing: "Package" on Configuration Default to iphone
running s3e_deploy commandline: "e:\marmalade\6.2\s3e\python\python.exe" "E:\Marmalade\6.2\s3e\deploy\main.py" "-n" "--os" "iphone" "--arch" "arm" "e:\Marmalade\6.2\examples\s3e\s3eIOSNotifications\build_s3eiosnotifications_vc9\deploy_temp.py"
CWD=e:\Marmalade\6.2\examples\s3e\s3eIOSNotifications\build_s3eiosnotifications_vc9
Marmalade Deployment Tool v1.3
Copyright (C) 2001-2012 Marmalade
Licensed Platforms=NONE, current platform=iphone
WARNING: temporary folder already exists (e:\Marmalade\6.2\examples\s3e\s3eIOSNotifications\build_s3eiosnotifications_vc9\deployments\default\iphone\release.old)
deploying s3eIOSNotifications [0.0.1] [arm-release] for 'iphone' to folder: 'deployments\default\iphone\release\intermediate_files'
--> copying files ...
Not using generic splashscreens for iOS
--> updating s3e binary: compression=none signing=0 config-embedding=1
 [execute] s3e_mod.exe
--> performing custom deployment steps for: 'iphone'
Linking iOS loader with extension library s3eIOSNotifications
 [execute] ld64.exe
WARNING: No iPhone portrait splashscreen specified.  Using the generic splash screen.
WARNING: No iPad portrait splashscreen specified.  Using the generic splash screen.
WARNING: No iPad landscape splashscreen specified.  Using the generic splash screen
WARNING: Expanding smaller image (e:/marmalade/6.2/examples/resources/splashscreens\splash_640.png) to (768x1024)
 [execute] s3eRelocate
 [execute] mod_apple_loader.pyc
Embedding provisioning profile in app
signing with Developer entitlements: NOT for App Store
provisioning profile does not specify 'aps-environment' - push notifications and email will not work
App ID from info.plist: 38ZJGRK9WD.38ZJGRK9WD.com.findandtry.findandtry2
Provisioning profile app ID matches: 38ZJGRK9WD.com.findandtry.findandtry2
created temp.xcent
 [execute] codesign.exe
creating .app zip: deployments\default\iphone\release\s3eIOSNotifications.app.zip
adding app_dir to zip: deployments\default\iphone\release\intermediate_files\s3eIOSNotifications.app
creating IPA: deployments\default\iphone\release\s3eIOSNotifications.ipa
creating ipa: deployments\default\iphone\release\s3eIOSNotifications.ipa
adding app_dir to zip: deployments\default\iphone\release\intermediate_files\s3eIOSNotifications.app
SUCCESS (WITH WARNINGS): EVALUATION USE ONLY package written to 'e:\Marmalade\6.2\examples\s3e\s3eIOSNotifications\build_s3eiosnotifications_vc9\deployments\default\iphone\release' [took 4.16s]. This package is not licensed for commercial use
```

The mkb file:
    #!/usr/bin/env mkb
    files
    {
        s3eIOSNotifications.cpp
    }

```
subprojects
{
    ExamplesMain
    s3eIOSNotifications
}

assets
{
    (data)
}

deployments
{
    iphone-sign-for-distribution=0

    # Note the App/Bundle ID must be set to the same value as an app registered
    # through iTunes Connect or the app will not be recognised by Apple's APNs
    iphone-appid="38ZJGRK9WD.com.findandtry.findandtry2"

    # A provisioning profile, set up to use the same full app/bundle name, must
    # also be embedded or the app will not be able to retreive a token for
    # remote notifications.
    iphone-provisioning-profile="FindandTry.mobileprovision"
}
```

I'm using Marmalade 6.2.1, tried both RVCT and GCC compilers for ARM, building standart example of s3eIOSNotifications as-is. I explores .ipa file and compare .provisionprofile files inside .ipa and original - there are identical. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Explaining iOS builds made using marmalade:-

**Development build**
When making development build, you do not need to add a provisional profile, in the deploy tool or mkb. The device needs to have development provision profile installed in it, or need to be embedded in the ipa (just open the ipa in winrar and put the `mobileprovision` file, renamed as `embedded.mobileprovision`). That's just for development build.

**Release Build**
To make a release build you need to provide specific release provision profile (not the development one) from either deploy tool or mkb file. Just including the profile in mbk will convert the build as release. The most important thing is, you can't install a release build using `ipcu` or `iTunes` (Dunno about any other method) even in devices with development profile installed. The release build is just for submission to the app store.

So the point is, just ignore the provision profile section if you are just testing the build in device. Only include the profile, if you're actually going to submit the same build to app store.